# How can I increase the signal intensity and precision?

Tags: chromatography

How can I increase the signal intensity and precision when use HPLC or LC-MS/MS ? How Also prevent Contamination and Carryover during Analysis

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! You can visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) if you had any questions about the policies of this site. It might help you get answers. Or, you can just take a [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: This is any extremely broad question and you could probably write a book to answer it. Also, strategies for optimizing an HPLC or LCMS method strongly depend on what you are analyzing, the method that you are using, and the specific problems you are seeing. If you have more specific questions, you might get some answers.